# Matching multiple levels of a URL into a string in a RequestMapping

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I'm trying to write an API that makes a request based on file paths. I'd like to make a request mapping like so:

```
@RequestMapping("/home/{path}")
```

(where path gets mapped to a String)

The problem is the {path} variable only matches a single component of the URL.
So if I do request /home/hello/myfile.jpg I get a 404. I'd like that to put hello/myfile.jpg into the path string instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that path variables can't expand over path separators. You could do it manually, something like:

```
  @Controller
   class HomeController {

        private urlPathHelper = new UrlPathHelper();

        @RequestMapping("/home/**")
        public String test(HttpServletRequest request) {
            String path = urlPathHelper.getLookupPathForRequest(request);

           ....
        }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, looks like it will work, but I decided to use a path parameter instead.